# parsing a python string with floats and ints

Tags: python, parsing, floating-point, int

I have hundreds of string that all have the same format -- 2 integers followed by three floats.  An example:

```
1 10 1.2345 5.4321 10.5647
```

I just want to take these strings one-by-one and parse them into their respective ints and floats.  I can think of a few ways to do this, but I was hoping that python would have something elegant, kind of an inverse of the `str.format` thing that gets used for writing.  This seems like very basic functionality, so I'm sorry if I am asking something that has been answered, but I can't find a solution anywhere.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: My organization's firewall blocks the site.

Comment: Heh, they don't want you to try too hard, I guess?  It starts: "If you’re a developer and you’re about to ask another developer a technical question (on a forum, via email, on a chat channel, or in person), you’d better be ready to answer the question “What have you tried?”"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be best off with something like numpy's `genfromtxt` or `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
import StringIO

s = """1 10 1.2345 5.4321 10.5647
       2 14 434.35 345.34 1000000
       3 8  253.235 2.53 .002345"""
f = StringIO.StringIO(s)

data = np.genfromtxt(f, names = 'id, count, x, y, z', dtype=[int,int,float,float,float])
```

This gives you an array of these things, so the first row is accessible as

```
data[0]
#(1, 10, 1.2345, 5.4321, 10.5647)
```

Or all the second column:

```
data['count']
#array([10, 14,  8])
```

By the way, this will convert an integer in the float column into a float, in case one of your floats happens to be an integer.

Answer (score 4):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick

```
>>> mystr = '1 10 1.2345 5.4321 10.5647'
>>> [int(s) if s.isdigit() else float(s) for s in mystr.split()]
[1, 10, 1.2345, 5.4321, 10.5647]
```

Comment: This would convert negative integers to floats.  Probably that wouldn't be an issue, but `ast.literal_eval` would avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def linep(line):
    line=line.split()
    try:
        ints=map(int, line[0:2])
        floats=map(float, line[2:5])
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
    return ints+floats

print linep('1 10 1.2345 5.4321 10.5647')
```

Then use it this way:

```
>>> s='''1 10 1.2345 5.4321 10.5647
 -2 11 -0.5 0.5 .3'''
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     print linep(line)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 10, 1.2345, 5.4321, 10.5647]
[-2, 11, -0.5, 0.5, 0.3]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Something like that was one of my options.  I was hoping for something short and sweet, though, kind of like formatted output in reverse.